# Custom Django workflow

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I'm a newbie in Django and have written the login/registration procedures.

Currently, on clicking the submit button to login, I'm navigated to a page `www.example.com/login`. Similarly, when I try to logout, the logout is successful and the URL is `www.example.com/logout`. On successful registration, the URL is `www.example.com/register` though the `register` and `login` functions use the same template. I know this is because I modified the urls in `urls.py` in such manner.

I want to keep the urls same (`www.example.com`) no matter if the user logs in, registers or logs out. How can I do that?

This is my `urls.py` file:

```
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

    from django.contrib import admin
    admin.autodiscover()

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', 'website.views.home', name='home' ),
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
        url(r'^login/$', 'website.views.user_login'),
        url(r'^register/$', 'website.views.user_register'),
        url(r'^logout/$', 'website.views.user_logout'),
    )

    from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

My `views.py` file: http://dpaste.com/1196312/

Comment: You mean, that **after** login/logout/register it is needed to redirect to one url (`www.example.com`), or it is needed to **perform** all actions at same url. I.e. if user is logged-in, then at this single url he will be prompted to logout, and if not, he will see maybe two forms, one for login and one for register ?

Comment: @stalk: The latter one. Currently, I've made the home page to show both forms. But still, I want to make the URL same. If you want to have a look at my `views.py` file: http://dpaste.com/1196312/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [django-multiurl](https://github.com/jacobian/django-multiurl). This package allows to use same url for different views.

I think, that in your case you'll probably need to create one additional view for rendering login and register forms on GET request.

Here is how to get started:

urls.py:

```
from multiurl import multiurl

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'website.views.home', name='home' ),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    multiurl(
        url('/your_single_auth_url/$', 'website.views.user_logout'),
        url('/your_single_auth_url/$', ''website.views.show_register_or_login_forms'),
        url('/your_single_auth_url/$', ''website.views.user_login'),
        url('/your_single_auth_url/$', ''website.views.user_register'),
    )
)
```

views.py:

```
from multiurl import ContinueResolving
from django.http import Http404


def user_logout(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        logout(request)
        return render_to_response('index.html', RequestContext(request))
    else:
        # continue to search needed view
        raise ContinueResolving


def show_register_or_login_forms(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # on GET request show two forms, one for register and one for login
    else:
        raise ContinueResolving

def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check, if login form was submitted here
        if is_login_form:
            # login user here
        else:
            raise ContinueResolving
    else:
        raise Http404

def user_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check, if register form was submitted here
        if is_register_form:
            # register user here
        else:
            raise Http404
    else:
        raise Http404
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try ClassBasesViews and Do something like this:

```
class Website(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Your Website Code
        pass

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Register Code

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Logout Code

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Login Code
```

Than you have 4 Actions Urls (Rest) Now you just need to pass the right methods to your forms and it will do it correctly, also your url needs some upgrade:

```
url(r'^$', 'Website.as_view()', name='home' ),
```

the rest isn't necessary then